# How to import Gmail contacts to Alpine?

Tags: alpine-mail, google, gmail

I tried the solutions provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/55124/how-can-i-use-my-gmail-contacts-within-alpine-pine), but they didn't worked.

In particular, `google.py` gives me this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 9, in <module>
    for b in r:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 314, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16.py", line 67, in _buffer_decode
    raise UnicodeError("UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM")
UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

and `pull_contacts.py` gives me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pull_contacts.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "pull_contacts.py", line 39, in main
    contacts = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/contacts/service.py", line 104, in GetContactsFeed
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.contacts.ContactsFeedFromString)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1108, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 401, 'body': '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<title>Error\n401\n(Client Error)!!1</title>\n<style type="text/css">\n        *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAADVCAMAAAAfHvCaAAAAGFBMVEVYn%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2Bex%2B3U5vd7s%2Bfq8%2Fs0itq72PMLUPvtAAASvklEQVR4AbXBC0JqCQxEwT5Jd7L%2FHc8FdR4g%2BEGtEr8u%2FBHxu7otdzd%2FQPyqlmRp1Pw%2B8aukDfRa1fw28ZtWy4sa89vEb7LCi0zx28RvqgkvouW3id%2FU8pbtWmv5beJXRWNrRmp%2BnfhlHXZm%2BQPi95Vk%2FoD4fZbMHxC%2FryTzB8Tva435A%2BL3rcb8AfH7VjJ%2FQPy%2BHYk%2FIH5facwfEL8iaZcrnKyn%2BAPi57K2VL2WF1hJ%2FAHxQ2tJrg6HteXVjPkD4ge6V3J1%2BF97zhx%2BnXhWb8nacKXlnYPErxNPyfqw4ZYKVuUZdfhd4hmxunY73NICgfWMOvwm8ZQ1pMvlDZdaCic98kjV4beIp8ScpLvsSvhflzqQmqVLB281v0E8pc2bdNne8EayNTPNSbt02PBj4intcKltb%2FNibY%2BLf9aSO%2FyMeMo6XMva3g0vwrWsxvyMeEoc3knZ2g53ZaXa8DzxlHa4J23Jae5aycXTxFPa4WRdXAtdsivckZXG4TniKWtOSlre6y7LG651Wxq5OzxDPGUVIKNwX6ekCv%2B0ddglVPMM8ZQ10FJ4LGVvOEuXRl7OqnmGeEor4Ck%2BtnI1ZEvjDa%2FcPEM8ZQVY4RO9VqUlN%2F84PEM8JQ50cUgXH2mrKlyq5RniOQ4vVjPLHdu86OKGi2eIr%2BgNV6JwljmYO6zlbJsbWp4hPtVrjYpLLV7UHIp7rOVkixtaniE%2BU5I2Nc2FKJytZhTuiac5rLnh4hniEzUbDjXhn3g5W0nNA1aAKm7YPEN8bMecrZYLWl70hkcyBay5YfMM8aHI4aR7xAUVHyirOdhAmRsqniE%2BtOKsRjIXtDzmmRGHVmDFDRfPEB%2BJzMmO01xScdYnVRs6vPHMFG9W4ZrMM8RHouWw43DNhlDWiSVZY3nDoWYc3qzDNZlniPe6w4uoOFjcKhPXuJNWyG6VqjSuhm7%2BiZorUfEM8U5J8nKyMw0tcZLwPxdRtTlUcUgVdGlml0uZ4pqKZ4hr5VUnpSXdUgVa4hA5vHERV1Tp9XhdJTWHksYd%2Ftdarql4hrjQiaPiYLclNSeebVYz5o0W7Ghsa9blmlFtx01rxP8yy5XIPEP8L1W7bjWHlbzhRTwjzXrCK1f3qqSEyBysLVtayKp40yqurcITxJtUgavVHNob%2FinZTWt5VVvWVKvJSttQCkRjb%2FA4vLK5thOeIN6sm9ai5cTFhYRDy%2FyTGpdU0hxkaZvWUrZluTmLims14QniVbywClqgeouT9IZXNWoupGzNqHa3y5LGVYBnipbCSVxcq1meIN54oRXsbEk26S3NmBcZ807K3gon2ZLcxF5tPMVJprlWE54g3nihtbRHm7WjkbxTHSCWwj1r2U4HSMmdQEmWwonNtah4gnhjA9ZSaohmpnpDjWRptDwS25LcQGsc2Bla5sTFtZV4gnixpWmIVWpgRuVwsiV5q7kv0JJcNVIFapydUrHTQKa5IfMEcRKrurSQ0qhsmVR4kea%2B7pIr9NqSrRltWlaxomUgVVyLxBPEYeUGygtszew2KfOBclVpVN2ctCXNidZaaKWmONhc6rKaJwi6xuGkRmWpAkRa7outF9XN%2F7LlmbJmpiCyvBxk%2FtnSqHmGWGk5i2ZcaWBLau5KKHt3Ce%2FsaLMz46VG4cTFm%2FaMOzxFUYWztjzhkNI43JPyYvPAegPxzFRpOYmWF1WywrPUag5xjRapqqxxubijvYFVaC%2Fv7YSDpzxjzlbhpKXxhqcpWshqtECk0Yys6m5utZdD1LCuCifhfyVOapqsxhyiQMmSm58QNdZheZGV5FqwueXiZBUga28DvRte1NQCpQVSUkFqPbIr%2FIxg7arwJqqEg6e5Vuas1Zytyw1ka5uT9ajKI87WbksaLT8mbkXFyWqaa2rOVuFVStUNpGrDoSTPmDfWdlby8kPiHQtoa0vLpXU4WzX%2FS5W2gWxtOHQ24U3CSUmu8BPinR2XVSFyuNAOZ9Fyae1qDu2qcF8suRKeJt7pcW1zaE9xwcVZq7nWtpeTrQ0PrEeq8CTxnsWrlbThELra5ixqbsXWNoeq6nBft6TlOeK9VnG2lfb4TKOOlpOouKPsWg4pb3Nf1uMGusP3iDtKDaTcgMuWvL1FmZOouCtlbwJs1Yb7SuN2Nd8k7mgvXV4OKWALiGkVJ14eyPqQQG9Vc0dWGnn5LnFPTW1z1gW0OdSyag5aHsvaroVs1YZL2dKMt1nzXeKulas52QLanGy3xq4a87Eu2yHZ2uZNWzPjDbDmu8R9a8m7iQNscbKyy%2BWS%2BUzWtqp7qzpA1jPj8KKK7xIPZG2NVWTTSbpKbs5cfEF6y64qV6ctqcKbdvgm8VhSlnWwJbuaV3LzRb11onFt%2BKcVvkl8one7u3bD%2FzJuXnRt%2BFTXVHOWqubQ4rvEEyI1L1Z2h8%2B0eRHLKiBqvkk8IePmxZq1lk%2B0w0nJUHKIlm8ST8ioeVEFtFwbPhA3h8gcdpZV803iCRkVL7Y42bK2w0NlDqXlpJRV803iGZYrnFRxlqwO3eEuN4dSOGlVme8Sz7C37QZqeZPekl0b3nMBreKsp1bNN4lnWIEtF1Vc6i1bVZtwxQX0NC9UrfBN4hk7zaHLNrey1kgVLljATnO2rmj5JvEMqzlrF%2B%2BFXitcsAArnFkdLd8knrFqPmFzyQq0xUm0tJZvEs8oAR0eix0u1ARSqg70NNHyTeIZUqgZ85gdLlgcMjOSRlBqvkk8wwOSp3moJlyoCYfeKkmBVvgm8YyaUJJ5zOJSTXMWSgus%2BC7xjJpA%2BMiquVATXiUcSuGbxDNqmk%2BUxtW82WmurMI3iWd4wifaHo1rNxx2miul8E3iGTXhc4nH0lQ1O80VK3yTeEYNX5SspbEnXFmFbxLPqGm%2BrsvWFFdK4ZvEM2rCt6RmzCWL7xLP2Anfs2M3Fyy%2BSzyjpvmqDoed5YrFd4ln7DRftHI19BRXSuGbxDN6wtdEqjF4lisS3yWeEYUvWlkDNeZKTfgm8ZFu7mqFr%2FKMYae4lFH4JvGBVLgraghf09uQMZdabr5JfKC2q1zV3IgarOLLPMWllptvEo%2B1e7dkq5ZrLkip%2BKqa4lLk5ZvEY15INay9XIqXVGS%2BqsdcirzclYVa7hAPbQFVnJSaC9HCapavqjGXIjXvbNmSxi7eE4%2BsA21OumwuSQUJX1ZjLsVabqR6t7tUlrThhnjEC%2FFy6AKbCy45zdftmEutKm5UcSgHspY7XBEPVAFVHLoCUXPFkr3hi2wutba44QDr5iyeqQ3%2FiAccqOLQDhAV17pG0jZfUuZS5OJaGYiWF%2B2ypOV%2F4q5UQZtDu4G2xK10aeTlC1bhUslciQpYh7PSQtau8ErcVYZ4gXYDcUXLe1lrvBU%2B0VoutFRcWQWo4qwdTlYSr8Q9caDMwc3BDgl3xZpRb%2FORnuVCJHNlla2oOYmLQ8q7Ll6Ie6pgDaQKSCl8IF3WqAgPrbgU2VxpV1kje2EdoOWGlsOJuKMd1g14OdjNp1YjNY%2B0m0s15kYgJVlaFxBVOETuAOK9eEELrDmUli%2Fo8oy94S4Xl2LzQGukEFU46RptQLy3BWWgHSBTvEp32eGRtjTjSriQBKLlShUPrSRcnK2qtIB4Zw3tQNRAbF5FB0vhoS57JFXzZmUtuLiy5gNlTTixlkgB8Y4byhAX0HJ4Y%2FcmWkjz0NrSaMNJ5EiNi3%2FSpPlIayqA3UBcIG5tQTuwBcQOJx3AsrSzxHJ4bKs9U5xoqWnK4U17%2BUzPFLQ4iQ3iRtxQC3gBK5xZJjOutcaSpeYjsUZqKFmGOLxIaflU1jI2ZzuLuLGuLe2yBlrLC1tdWg7ZmWal8KHeGtXG0gLLSdZyha%2BoKYdDl7WIGxpbI7lSicyLqFkH2rVZF%2BwUnymNXNu8WUkVLqSaB6IpIGWXF3Ft1UC6rRq3mhc7TRXgLS2lrKb5VEoz6nCSrtE2V6p4aMeQ8tJaxLU4nGU9o%2BXVTrMF%2BLBgjYqvSNkjL%2BDxhmut5tDb3CF1uwJoEdday6vMTHjVs7GA3g3QU8tXxZJc6Q23yhxWckPCtZW1nLgQ12KFF5Ed3pQ0U7yKp%2Fi6YM%2FI4dZOA3FRRdvhSmaWMxtxI3JzVlP8k9qsVFWdbVvTfENCjcytUoBW46XscE3DizLi1o6KQ4%2FDlZRsWSfBCt%2BSdHGrzGHFOtjFtUgNNJQR78Qjr%2BVwzV4I65SazPJzrQbKq6bl5kapU7bbRryXLo3c3LATYIfMEs3yc1bA44bScqumvJ21jLgrhHdSktNWkONR%2BLmULMnbpQm3pOWkZxHf0R7NKKykDr9iq3ptuexOuJQRZ5lCfE96K5Ct5iNpe118WQKxVeGCxnYDmUL8iUjb2%2BXmexIu9Di9XtgpxJ9wcehuOzwt1gJx4ynEM9K9tS5X7fLempP2dmnDczwjTlLYi%2FiCnHXSe9LWic9k3qvlRTltLU%2Bp2lE1sKUG8bm2DiNpNBpJu5vwwuEdLa%2FWy6p4JL27Dg%2B0pUBsQHxu67C1Vb2dpLlU5h3bG87aS0vNXWtJtip0bbjDhqgB8TkvH1g115qttnfDoW0oNe%2B1Rs0hlqVRc8cSmYP4XBUfUXHNlQ5tqzkpNaXmHVV4lVpq1NxjhYP43JqP2FwracOh7OZQDuXmRmu5sjMO75SWE%2FE5F4%2F09s5wI5abQ0rFoVxZNTes7e7wvy053NpwJj7n4kVCDt29teWypJHFOy0VJ6sN0CrK4dpakmv5pxQeEZ8rQ%2B9alnU2knyo2k64Ix4vh5I5sVNarqW3u8z%2F4mkeEZ8LrCxXtbfWu9t8qqQK0DKHVtEubrWm%2BZ9VPCS%2BJN1828oB4gqwalrFtUjNP3bzkPg7sdXAyhyssF4upWb5Z8c8Jv5QWmpgVRxUsGoulMw%2FPQqPiZ%2Fp8JGVOLQWKAW6%2BCcyF2qGD4gfibe2ead5lXEDpQAu0rv8r2WgtZxl1Twm%2Ftls1HxHK7HDjZV51VIgWmBlSeMKr%2BxseZYXq%2BUx8aY0MxrvVnUC4XNxgYtrJY15taMmNlAztd0lhxfW6MChC1rFY%2BLVjlwzKutVdfhE7xjKXEiX3CuHFzWG0lLycogUXnTtxuaws6DiMfFK09kZQ9K1VSvJ3oRHslIFWuGftdzQUoWzlYONinBILRdaC8TTYPO%2F3nBFnKxLG2um%2BKfXOrg6vBdLrvJSCm9SJpy0RtucrMRq1Zy1woUy0B4HbN60ex0uiEN0KLk1xZXs2paKW9FIqrJrzP%2Fs5k17tJz0GE%2FxohwulGElOUTmTRWl5oI4lKRRsTPhVpIdc6sl10IsFW9WXNpROPH0TkGAVnFpx5a63WSKN5HVXBKwc1btEffsNO8kvBObS5lZTnaUMXFYqbnUltwg75h%2FusMVATXleWW7qk1Xb8KLVfiKlsIlj9Sc1FhFtjITboSTlSp8QMCO5JU11bb1ZlQdIHL4iprmktWROclqGlaWmvsSPiRAIy3lcAhk05vsWgfbU3xFVFyRWTUvSqqa2S7zHEFmRikt7yS18kxxFj6yY67UbNu86U6qIApPEUSasZb7Ek0DqXh5LHa4lDFWc6kd4uUpgsiaKR6pKQ61uHmsZrmyk1ZxpQ1oeYoAzaG4ry1zsuXisVJxpeQdc60N2DxFgGckc1ePixdpHkjVjrnS0kpc6u5SwMtTBKxkybUJN3bUfCaulsMVTVvNP%2BmyNQVe7tjlE%2BJFb1mSLVfV9jaHHS2fiao15sqOd4pL29ArbxXvldV8TPwv6XVV6YXtGTefiiqaMRei2TFXKpzUONxKFWo%2BJt5J0ltlzQxfsCqimSpv86KmrHApBbXA2s2NuKPwMfFQvOELWgvsnEjVQMYtc2UXqjm0xI0yq%2FAx8T0JtyJz8DiekWpjxWoupRqqOamp5VJPsXJt9256wz3iW8oOt1xNaWah3NZJZK7UAg6HLo%2B5tFPgke2SreUe8R1rO9xayTpALFaa2Z3mUhyo4qQ6I67MbLlsyyfFPeI71m7ey0orw2pL256WuFILVHOI41mu1IyK3u0q28094nvCXQHLtqyF9Gq5tA7E4bAViRsrNW%2FCXeK3lDTVVoBI4ZIDVHFYpbTcyIbPiF%2FTSbPT3SUtl6qAuDl4W8UzxC%2Fz6CRciALUcijT4inil%2FV2p4pLtUDcwCol8xTxF8KlKg5VQGtb4jniz7UbWAcox%2BJJ4s%2B5OLiAVnuKJ4m%2FtuawBURbszxL%2FLF4OXgh9s7yNPHHqjisgVLLPE%2F8rXYD7UCrVsXzxN%2Bq4uAGrFj8gPhTXRzKwGprmh8Qf2rlot2AvSp%2BQvyl1nikAlprh58Qf0lqolGBarX8iPhLZWBVqnVsfkb8pTaHcru61PyM%2BEtrDq2UW8sPib%2FUChBvbIcfEn%2FKxWGrpeWnxJ9qVYDyVPgp8bfa2qRmmh8Tf21lq5qfE38uveE3%2FAdr385%2FSVd%2FMAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D) 100% 5px no-repeat;margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{padding-right:205px}p{margin:22px 0 0;overflow:hidden}ins,#g{text-decoration:none}ins{color:#777}a img{border:0}#g{background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAA3CAMAAADZn0ObAAABgFBMVEX%2F%2F%2F%2Fy1pHuLjfMm2W4yfA1TrPukgZDats3V8fwTEypjWy8u7oPsSWVsOoBdwwClhI%2FZdlasGjpOUOVlJjx0c20CyZpea36pAdIdebyu7COlqpYaql2hLH40Gn59vayuMlZiOunpqjYGy9wiNLd5PRqlOzzcmz%2Fwi4FpRrqsDisbm7O2O%2FKycrGfHmdo7CFmdPs7Ozz8%2FPIDSvcFC%2BTR0vCw8Xj5OTc3Nynvu7l6%2FfVjyw7Xc%2FSMT%2FZbgbT09NDbuHKz9BKf1Hr5ubiHTLt8vz%2Btxj1%2BOrT1txYedhLcNfwjYjTES6yq6r27Oqnq7NJZsiykpDNEiyxUVOTptiys7LNs6%2FhegO3p5L46MRveZiXcHBFXbY5dkLUysj0Pj9OfOjRS1JVZZzMrZGoXWCzKjn%2BrgpcdsflfIKh26frpKHJGzIqxDe4cC2AoOnOXl%2FYaWx204D4XVWsPEjRXwXqoRqYFSnN5dBhfMwZjipRaLvUmpk3x0SualZBXcJIV5A9nk5h34NHAAAJe0lEQVRo3u1YC1fa2BYGBBJA2lSeRjzyUKmQQgJNAoYhlJciiKJYHx2hYm2rre2140zHmem9f%2F3uE16JOpVZpcuuu%2B5eLpeSsPOdb3%2Fn2%2FtEp%2Ft%2FdAOV3%2F4L4tGj39DI3ynOp%2BznEPaUcZ77LqjKb%2F989%2Be7d5OPreKIDygaz9teWSYIgpJlb9u%2FnUqj8cP6jX87OTn58Pd6dqTkabvfS6z66FgsEKN9rymi4l31x6NjB1YWeODqwTNbfpTURgDlpgNNPrciilmGj7kpQEZQIaE4bmDcJIbFsyPUD6iq%2BGK2rMAhWARCnJCNbVAUJZlCwrgJ44Cth8%2F4u6U1f%2B4nrhwBRs0rYvkr0mQ6CqyMvY5KEe%2BGVTz3y18czetbgxM3TEcO29jZQiD5EYqIoILSfl3UPB7%2FEzW5AdX4nWtyJLZSfi81E8jdvM04Z%2BOF7%2BBdI0l%2BfsFPbDhuuwsJYn78zgVsvRuBLVzCmYB42%2FPRjQ%2B%2FFSUatYhpv18m923sSDmd02uLb9ZOnTdSoj19GMesfq94DXoxajSmcNjt9nP7vALroaaI65B1cXFtWl2a1IKX%2BuIYpROg6YtWy2IxtOD3mra6e7Ph8FJnYqlUAmR76ksoeu5vt%2F0QbS9BUXGoyjW21tcsEDiz5XS4XOiD1FXgbmUj52Lrw2ataatZpyAs00P3L8%2BGS52mzcbYdjGwkp4bAIv65VA8vkrIXmgibndgDlyoxxbXS3thmKjVms0nsNypjyzq17AN0mreXUOg6knNlhUFYWXnpWFqqvAH1xfgbHhpN8CLLMsKzNJJqXTSYfvW027XAe8cTcEA8Dlg40Xc%2FcHkB7CmLwyb8F3I2pkyGApP2P5yvLLkvltagOqDg1esFbGHUwVDIbnDDriy1rPdf7js5UnpxNNBvd0k082sAHDj0Mgo3wrbk%2FwAlvOiFQkcYkUgdsKQDJ71koJpEZL7rt0KFbQYHAC%2B%2Bzjuj0KhkMxklW%2FthcPLjqHrdU5OTjyXilah%2FbsDue5KQhRBSXPdZw7ZWsdpe%2BJHzmDD5Yp0LcHexmzd5W1o7cKwpTIR9iXAqkbymKxw%2BNLazA%2BHzyWAZe4Ar8UFv%2BzuXUE5SqYkd7bL1gAW1ODlIO1p8sz160GuD4ugru6C5bywGI5VlUanAKtxxkBqPYbFDNlGsxjWMnxi9Lep%2FX4dUFumKLKbogsL%2FkSLF4bjZrey05ag6%2BmBw9Zjy%2BuVqas7tAVktYIHTHn4SR6zldgUMFklszWn8oQ9DMvcyWOfptxM%2F4odpiQyhnc8etyHBcpq%2FYWfjU5bhUwk0MSTVVdbMCZLG%2FWvw1oHsgCWeuyxFJIJ1%2FEKAmWVLq3q4QctAaznVlG30Maw%2BjwaoYgmWtBoaxrybvHrzkVD4cNms8mIfX%2FQGTFbEv1133KCiQYjakp0bzCspwyCGp6YrZpTzCyGtZxDAIvYGMgjKlMkGRCHbAGsNUvLsLVrmZqaAKIYYWh3unlZhqK7v%2B7yzlbLEPxLM2NMK7B4Ftzh0mxVf72sx7DeM9w5WChVFwYPosgjxbaHkl%2BDvJkafzhnUxHVlyKwtTF3rYqoiFuY3b5tj8ejnLNlMAS3NC7iTCYbrqc2Vh8uAVu8SnY6DOuX9zkuRcjYq1CfLcnUbb0qtiBvdXdFEPLsdVq2KVmpItIegwh8wvD7VwnpNZN3GqYMyVeafeEsJF2YLQXWshoW2jsxm3%2BCXZCGnkMR%2FQWnMFnXDOLUAMuN3DqVRzEsqsJwmhOjfTtG03SlQpAmmmed0BaCZ7uCBlbV5TrguT3oNR5zTY14D2r4C9QVzcHSiNcrSvNkocU5ugsbsqXkfZm7zcu5z7gvSNoDDhKyh7ksT0gSaXKs4H1XKFQj6pnMmay6foXBQ3FPj1V9Se8x%2F%2FQei3t9W5IkahUAoKifUgZwFVsAcR23weDmrTaQkzAuStutOY5D3DxBwdmnBiSBexaCGX5dJXmseGxDeo%2Fn0rOsJnvWA2QpxLD1K1KiZP%2F5gp%2BC415v5ejxwx5baDEDiTPMbVUshiQMrHKTyzQBZJnw7lnPBIPBs01VFd9gsvCK2UsPdk%2FVpRLsQ4fSLxGbi%2FncvpAfj%2BW2QYOa7MMCKeD1frjtcIXmK11cN6SXhu7aZQvtVBvVaoYf3IEymCxcOqQ3m82eS35gOnuYrL7QubzI8CFvBY90%2FRvQ48F0yj2B5RYKH2%2FFlfsCVMPGuz5HpCu4iIrzlJ80Go3qh4GEFmEbOhjl2cXOcwC21L9ULsE2rA21hrhiCDbVl9iQz2GrRvlMo5pMBl86UX8Czg%2BFZCNJDEze1tpHmiB7RYRaRRKJBOBSJnUEJXw6OCyxHTMAW4LMCI85gCqmFcS5TBDgFP0hH7T14MHPTcVT0OGrRqKRTBY%2BnjoF5%2FSbzI4KAj7XY2BESGOraShhjy1Y1%2BYrVyKRWXM6naeZ6quDAN8f58vpnWXAdbKk1%2BvDnucTjmZWS3u0QmAb3O7l%2Fs8DJX5%2F9hZr4HDL5Uo0EkkgrZo429G8cOCyPpMJkFHE6rZxXllWMWqvAFemf%2FfmfMTyB5%2FOgLFktfoJmj0zfPmF2OyudRkUZjYvd3abvPZwl45GV7F4ZSqkMCE8evazEo%2B68hI3P7m68eo4YBM5rVHZ3BiYRMKyVldDqxUJCni0f%2BQIMOzgncRO5HhraysSqfGMoCEE5W2d5YnliYldGNdVZUinFioUQW68UGpBdM2RzfI2HoLpQkACv3n8FCLiqDE3tM%2BKPO1%2B8UIhjXxxdeWj6Rr09UNB9RROELM5hsmKLHf962VWWFkRRSFfVo0B522KCtGxer1Ov8DileJKq%2BZYTvnp38mxYpaBEIXbjvasyMRot3vmCE5ONA2TBhwOytcP1kiJrxyZ1e82CMrnCEAeURB5NwmWT%2F7NvIkQ%2BPffnicQmxdEMZuFVcNxBX3byR5QSfv4nMbhLYpEH%2BAifeI3vCYYx%2FuQ6IIXUDGDSqE8dBPTDMP9YzTjjDToinSoa4aEDRDtSC87vl8Y2xXCRGtKhuLA1j3DssPJRYppHcxOmvbvGxb4OqllSxeH4Y1B9woriseSDV4Nolgh92Pi%2FcLSKZPpa%2FWwFCdnHDx3v6h07GdoOFJlLq1TbEs3HyJn6PG%2FTf%2FH9ie6cY%2BViJA9lUqdQ7f2Be4fFfap2IzSYLG7k1c%2BGDp%2BAFTKJF%2FzufdnZtz7PrrevDZ03GPAaJDjbRA8dGsW6X6cgNmAhSEG%2FUiY%2Fsfiv02O7iVu1LunAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);display:block;height:55px;margin:0 0 -7px;width:150px}* > #g{margin-left:-2px}#g img{visibility:hidden}* html #g img{visibility:visible}*+html #g img{visibility:visible}\n      </style></head>\n<body><a href="//www.google.com/" id="g"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logo_sm_2.gif" alt="Google" width="150" height="55"></a>\n<p><b>401.</b>\n<ins>That&#39;s an error.</ins></p>\n<p>There was an error in your request.\n<ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p></body></html>', 'reason': 'Authorization required'}
```

Comment: Your links are not visible. But for `google.py`, try setting the encoding manually to  `utf-16-le` or `utf-16-be` since BOM is not found. The pull_contacts.py the error is an authorization error - see what you missed there

Comment: how do i set the encoding manually?

Comment: you must have opened the csv using `io.open` - there is argument where you specify the encoding

Comment: hello, neither of the encodings worked...